# Constants in static classes

Tags: c#, static, constants

With the use of static classes (and constant strings) I want to be able to get constant values like this:

```
var value = Constants.Labels.Controls.TopNavigation.Save;
```

I created this structure for this problem:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static class Labels
    {
        public static class Controls
        {
            public static class TopNavigation
            {
                public const string Save = "Save";
                public const string Refresh = "Refresh";
            }
        }

        public static class General
        {
            public static class Errors
            {
                public const string UnexpectedError = "An unexpected error occured.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, if I define everything in it, this will grow enormously.
What is the best way to split this into different/partial classes or folder structure so that this keeps maintainable. Keep in mind... To get the value, I always want to obligate the user to start with Constants.Labels....

If possible I would also like one class-file per lowest level...

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Updated... see tags ;) -> C#

Comment: Use Resource files

Comment: resource files are not an option

Comment: @RubenHerman Why is that?

Comment: You seem to be using nested classes like namespaces.

Comment: @RubenHerman You asked for the _best_ way to keep this maintainable. The _best_ way is resource files. If you have weird restrictions, do not ask for the best way (which is also usually highly subjective).

Comment: When C#6 is in use you will be able to add usings for static classes, you may as well use namespaces, if it is a requirement that they are fully qualified, add this to your coding standards/code reviews.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "maintainable"? You touch upon partial classes yourself. Any particular reason you're not already using this?

Comment: Resource files are not available because the business wants to be able to update all labels themself. Actually what is stored in the constant value is a KEY, in a sharepoint list, we retrieve the value in the correct language

Comment: @ Ben Robinson, indeed, like namespaces, but you are not obligated to use the Constants.Labels. ... instead, you can just start from Errors.Unexpected (if not nested static classes)

Comment: Will you be required to be able to store constants at every level? If so, then I would use partial classes. If not, I would use namespaces for those levels where you don't require this feature.

Comment: @RubenHerman, why not use resource files for the keys then? I.e. use the same value for the key and value in the resource files. It seems it would be easier to maintain this type of information in resource files than class files.

Answer (score 0):

you could use either resource files or an XML file to store them as key pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace Test
{

    public class TopNavigationConst {
        private const string SAVE = "Save";
        private const string REFRESH = "Refresh";

        public String Save {get{return SAVE; }}
        public String Refresh {get{return REFRESH;}}
    }

    public class ErrorsConst
    {
        public const string UNESPECTEDERROR = "An unexpected error occured.";
        public String UnexpectedError {get{return UNESPECTEDERROR; }}
    }

    public class ControlsConst 
    {
        private TopNavigationConst topNavigation = new TopNavigationConst();
        public TopNavigationConst TopNavigation {get{return topNavigation;}}
    }

     public class GeneralConst
    {
        public ErrorsConst errors = new ErrorsConst();
        public ErrorsConst Errors {get{return errors;}}
    }

    public class LabelsConst
    {
        public static ControlsConst controls = new ControlsConst();
        public static GeneralConst general = new GeneralConst();

        public ControlsConst Controls {get{return controls;}}
        public GeneralConst General {get{return general;}}
    }

    public class Constants
    {
        public static LabelsConst labels = new LabelsConst();
        public static LabelsConst Labels {get{return labels;}}
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var value = Constants.Labels.Controls.TopNavigation.Save;
            System.Console.WriteLine(value);

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Constant initializer must be compile-time constant. So doesn't work

Comment: You're right, in fact I tryed to translate a solution I've used in Java.

Comment: I edited the code with a working solution. But now it doesn't look so clean. I my case the code is generated automatically so it doesn't matter so much.

Answer (score 0):

If the class hierarchy does not provide any value other than organizing the constants, why not just use namespaces?

```
namespace Constants.Labels.Controls
{
    public static class TopNavigation
    {
        public const string Save = "Save";
        public const string Refresh = "Refresh";
    }
}
```

That way you meet your objective of one class-file per lowest level.

Comment: Indeed, but I want the developers to ALWAYS type the full name when accessing the value. If they just import the namespace, they can start immediatly with TopNavigation.Save

Answer (score 0):

The best solution (for now) for this problem was to work with partial classes. Disadvantage: There is some repeating structure for each file. Advantages: When the program expands, this file won't become huge. It's separated in more files AND I need to use the full name to get the correct value. So this was my preferred solution:

**------------TopNavigation.cs:------------**

```
public partial class Constants
{
    public partial class Labels
    {
        public partial class Controls
        {
            public partial class TopNavigation
            {
                public const string Save = "LABELS_CONTROLS_TOPNAVIGATION_SAVE";
                public const string New = "LABELS_CONTROLS_TOPNAVIGATION_NEW";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**------------Errors.cs:------------**

```
public partial class Constants
{
    public partial class Labels
    {
        public partial class General
        {
            public partial class Errors
            {
                public const string Unexpected = "LABELS_GENERAL_ERRORS_UNEXPECTED";
                public const string EmptyArgument = "LABELS_GENERAL_ERRORS_EMPTYARGUMENT";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If someone should post a better solution to my problem, I'll be happy to accept this as the correct answer.